# "Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.require.toUrl is not a function"

Tags: sapui5

An error is occurring while I am trying to learn Fiori. Any help will be appreciated.

In `onInit`, it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.require.toUrl is not a function.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  // ...
], function(Controller /*...*/) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("Upload_TestUpload_Test.controller.View1", {
    onInit: function() {
      var sPath = sap.ui.require.toUrl("Upload_Test/uploadCollection.json");
      this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(sPath));
    },

    // ...

  });
});
```

Sap UI Version : "1.52.12"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```js
> var sPath = sap.ui.require.toUrl("Upload_Test/uploadCollection.json");
> ```
>
> Sap UI Version : "1.52.12"

The API `sap.ui.require.toUrl` is available only as of **1.58.0**. If updating UI5 is not possible, you'll have to use the API `jQuery.sap.getResourcePath` instead:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "jquery.sap.global",
  // ...
], function(Controller, jQuery /*...*/) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("...", {
    onInit: function() {
      var sPath = jQuery.sap.getResourcePath("Upload_Test/uploadCollection.json");  // Use sap.ui.require.toUrl from UI5 1.58. The jQuery API is deprecated!
      this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(sPath));
      // ...
    },

    // ...
  });
});
```

[**API reference:** `jQuery.sap.getResourcePath`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.getResourcePath)